# Creating a table/organised list within a txt file

Tags: c++, text-files, spacing

I'm trying to create a table/organized list of values inputted by the user to be placed inside a txt file. Currently, I have double-pressed tab in order to space the numbers correctly, as seen below. Is there anyway to keep the spacing consistent, and is there anyway to have the program continue the table when it starts running again(If the program stops, it saves the file, but when started again it wipes the txt file)?

```
std::fstream file;

file.open ("southPN.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in );

file << id << "     " << resolved << "      " << halpha << "        " 
<< hbeta << "     " << o4959 << "     " << o5007 << "     " << n6548 << 
"     " << n6583 << "     " << s6716 << "     " << s6731 << "\n\n" ;
```

All the values (id - s6731) are inputted earlier in the program.
Some values are double/triple digits.

Comment: You probably need `std::setw`. You also need `std::fstream::app` to append to the file.

Comment: Techically its `std::ios_base::app` but `std::ios::app` and `std::fstream::app` boh work as well.

Comment: @DimChtz where would I put setw in the code? I'm a bit lost on how it formats the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look into I/O manipulators, specifically the `std::setw` which sets the width of the next output operation.

For instance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

file << setw(16) << id << setw(12) << resolved << setw(12) << halpha << ...
```

outputs `id`, `resolved` and `halpha` in fields of width 16, 12, and 12 respecitively.

You might also need `std::right` and `std::left` which switches from left padding to right padding (respectively). Unlike `std::setw` these change the stream for all subsequent operations (until you change it again).

Finally to append to your table add `std::ios::app` when you open the file

```
file.open ("southPN.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::app );
```

Comment: Ah that seems to be doing the trick. Do you know what the length of each field is? I've tried three different fields but there doesn't seem to be any baseline.

Comment: You mean the default width? I think the default is just enough space to fit the output.